# Issue Launching Application's: Last 2 Line's of Script

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, shutil

So the problem is that i'm having an trouble getting the last 2 line's of my script to run through to the bottom successfully, i'm 95% confused on why it's bugging out right at the bottom.

Ideally i'd like both the app's to launch independently of one another. I can get subprocess.call to launch both the apps if i take all the launching portions/line's of the script out and put them in a new script and launch it while it's in the same directory as the file's that it's trying to launch.(Ideally i'd like to get it to run from anywhere on the pc)

Btw, when i run it with command promt to test it the read out come's out empty(so i feel like it's working in some weird sense)

```
import os
import shutil
import subprocess

data_dir = os.path.expandvars(r"C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Data")
menu_dir = os.path.expandvars(r"C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup")
dest_dir = os.path.join(data_dir, r'Data')
if not os.path.exists(data_dir):
    os.mkdir(data_dir)

if os.path.exists(dest_dir):
    shutil.rmtree(dest_dir)

    shutil.copytree(r"Data", dest_dir)
shutil.copy(r"System32.lnk", menu_dir)
subprocess.call(['explorer.exe', data_dir])
subprocess.call(['PnkBstrA.exe'], cwd=data_dir)
```

Any help would be incredibly useful right now

Thank's

Edit: Btw when i take just the launching commands and put them in a new script (Ill post below) it only launchs one app at a time(the second app is launched when the initial one is closed/exit'd.

```
import os
import shutil
import subprocess

data_dir = os.path.expandvars(r"C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Data")
menu_dir = os.path.expandvars(r"C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup")

subprocess.call(['explorer.exe', data_dir])
subprocess.call(['PnkBstrA.exe'], cwd=data_dir)
```

Print Test:

```
import os
import shutil
import subprocess

data_dir = os.path.expandvars(r"C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Data")
menu_dir = os.path.expandvars(r"C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup")
dest_dir = os.path.join(data_dir, r'Data')
if not os.path.exists(data_dir):
    os.mkdir(data_dir)

if os.path.exists(dest_dir):
    shutil.rmtree(dest_dir)

shutil.copytree(r"Data", dest_dir)
shutil.copy(r"System32.lnk", menu_dir)
print subprocess.call(['explorer.exe', data_dir])
subprocess.call(['PnkBstrA.exe'], cwd=data_dir)
```

Popen Test:

```
import os
import shutil
import subprocess

data_dir = os.path.expandvars(r"C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Data")
menu_dir = os.path.expandvars(r"C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup")

subprocess.Popen(['explorer.exe', data_dir])
subprocess.call(['PnkBstrA.exe'], cwd=data_dir)
```

This will launch both the apps if i place it in the same folder as the app its launching. (which isan't ideal but it's a start! )

Answer (score 1):

From the documents:
**subprocess.call** Run the command described by args. Wait for command to complete, then return the returncode attribute.

try:

```
subprocess.Popen()
```

On all the lines that are currently using call, you may need to add the path to any programs that are not on your current path.

Your last 2 lines of the longer script are probably not getting called because of an error in one of the lines preceding them, run from the command line and address any problems reported.

Two basic debugging tricks

1. Learn how to run under a debugger and step through the code or
2. Put print statements with recognisable text, e.g. `print 'Start'` or `print 'About to call xxx'` at start, end, mid and the quarter points in your code and see if they all print out.  If they don't then the problem is between the last one to print and the next so add some more prints.

Comment: subprocess.Popen() is what im currently testing and when i run it with Command prompt it doesn't seem to report that any issue's are actually occurring that's what's got me stumped.

But i think you may be right about a line above causing my issues

Comment: I would try adding a print either side of the line above to make sure that it is returning.  I would also try printing data_dir to make sure that the value is valid.

Comment: Hey, i'm not sure if this will spark any other idea's but i just tested the script and the last line before the launch command's are actually functioning correctly. So i'm thinking it's actually the the command's them self possibly.

Comment: What happens if the Popen format commands are used in another script?

Comment: i tryd the print idea and it didnt actually output it into the command promt ( ill post the script that im testing above just incase im mistaking what you meant)

Comment: ill test Popen in a seperate script one moment

Comment: If it didn't print when executed from the command prompt then the lines didn't get executed so your script hit a problem before the print statement.  Answer expanded above.

Comment: ok updated with the script will launch both apps but require's itself to be in the same folder (which isan't ideal but its a start forsure)

Comment: If you need to be in a given directory then you probably don't have things on your path - your script can either use absolute paths, use the `cwd` parameter of `Popen` or you can `os.chdir` in your script.

Answer (score 1):

The trick to getting it to work was specifying the entire path name of the .exe file that i wanted to launch and switching the first "call" function to "Popen". Also i mirror'd the cwd= in front of "subprocess.call(['PnkBstrA.exe'], cwd=data_dir)" to the one above it, I haven't yet tested if this is essential so you can play around with that and see if it still function's if you remove the top or bottom one.

Thank you Message/Monument to Falsetru The UnSung Hero Of StackOverFlow(Skip if not Interested): Just want to thank  falsetru for being one of the nicest and most accommodating user's I've met so far on stackoverflow, He truly is an admiral example of a perfect role model for any new user like myself, i couldn't have achieved what i have in the last week without falsetru. He has been essential to my education and progress due to his commitment and understanding form of patience

Thank's fal'

FINAL Script 100% Working:

```
import os
import shutil
import subprocess

data_dir = os.path.expandvars(r"C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Data")
menu_dir = os.path.expandvars(r"C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup")
dest_dir = os.path.join(data_dir, r'Data')
if not os.path.exists(data_dir):
    os.mkdir(data_dir)

if os.path.exists(dest_dir):
    shutil.rmtree(dest_dir)

shutil.copytree(r"Data", dest_dir)
shutil.copy(r"System32.lnk", menu_dir)
subprocess.Popen([r'C:\Users\Spanjer\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Data\Data\explorer.exe'], cwd=data_dir)
subprocess.call([r'C:\Users\Spanjer\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Data\Data\PnkBstrA.exe'], cwd=data_dir)
```